# How to store Datagrid data to Database

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I want to store datagrid values into database. I have 1 column named project title. i want to add to database all the values that is under that column into database...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which language you are developing?

example in vb.net:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count

        Dim obj As Object = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value

        ' save in database

 Next
```

you can convert obj to your own type then save it in your db.

Answer (score 0):

This is the initial code for filling `DataGridView` and `DataTable`

```
    Private bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()    
    Private dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=<FilePath>;User Id=username;Password=password;"    
        Dim selectCommand As String    
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM...<YOUR SELECT Query>"    
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)

        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)    
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)    
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

        Dim data As New DataSet()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1    
    End Sub
```

This is what you want (Storing Datagrid data to Database using `DataAdapter`)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Me.bindingSource1 = Me.DataGridView1.DataSource    
        table = Me.bindingSource1.DataSource

        Me.dataAdapter.Update(table)    
    End Sub

End Class
```